# Почему ActivityStack несколько?

Tags: android, activity, backstack

Команда `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` показывает, что у нас есть несколько Stack-ов. Я так понимаю, что Stack - это [ActivityStack](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java). Почему их несколько, и что это для меня, разработчика, значит?